# How to get all parents associated to a child, one row for each association

Tags: sql-server, query, sql-server-2017, recursive

I have a table with two columns, Parent and Child. 
i need to get an output list showing a child and all associated parents, one parent per row. 
The youngest child will show as a child in rows equal to the total number of parents, as shown in the output table.

**Input table**

```
+-------+--------+
| Child  | Parent|
+-------+--------+
| b | a  |      
| c | b  |
| d | c  |
| e | d  |
| f | e  |
| x | f  |
+----------------+
```

**Output table**

```
+------------------------------+
| Child | Parent  | level  |
+------------------------------+
| a | NULL    | 0      |
| b | a   |
| c | a   |
| c | b   |
| d | a   |
| d | b       | 
| d | c   |
| e | a   |
| e | b   |
| e | c       |
| e | d       |
| f | a       |
| f | b       |
| f | c       |
| f | d       |
| f | e       |
| x | a       |
| x | b       |
| x | c       |
| x | d       |
| x | e       |
| x | f       |
+--------------------------+
```

Here is my syntax from SSMS 2017

```
create table tx  ( parent varchar(10), child varchar(10) )

insert into tx values
('a','b'),
('a','c'),
('b','e'),
('b','f'),
('a','d'),
('b','g'),
('c','h'),
('c','i'),
('d','j'),
('f','k'),
('x','y'),
('y','z'),
('m','n');


WITH REC AS (
SELECT child, parent
FROM tx 
UNION ALL
SELECT a.child, a.parent 
FROM tx A
INNER JOIN REC B ON B.parent = A.child)
SELECT Child, Parent
FROM REC
order by child
```

It is not giving me the results i expect as shown in the output table.

Any idea on how to modify my recursive query to get the output table?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: select  @@version returns  Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13-OD) (KB4483666) - 14.0.3049.1 (X64)   Dec 15 2018 11:16:42   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3245f9ca7018a06327190140c8d7ab8b) any help?